# clean $_GET var which was used in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I'm sending $.ajax to worker.php with this "data:pageref=streets&act=vw".
When I make echo of $_GET['vw']. I getting another value from different $_GET variable which was sent to worker php using ajax a long time ago.
How I should fix this? the first idea is to clean $_GET elements. any suggestions?

```
function ref() {
        //

        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "worker.php",
                data: "pageref=streets&act=vw",
                success: function(msg){
                    document.getElementById('main_street_res').innerHTML=msg;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I would use Firebug (or similar) take a look at what exactly is being sent in the HTTP request.

Comment: PHP scripts are "instantiated" on every call. It's not possible to have a $_GET from a previous call. I second the first commenter's suggestion to check what's being sent with Firebug.

Comment: sorry, mistyped. yes, I making echo using $_GET['act']. and I got this strange result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to echo `$_GET['vw']` ?

In `data` you pass `pageref=streets&act=vw`, so there are two keys: `pageref` and `act`.

If you echo `$_GET['act']` you will get `vw` - it does not work in the other way.

Answer (score 4):

You should echo `$_GET['act']` instead of `$_GET['vw']`
This is the probable error for getting junk values.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting so because you are doing `echo` to wrong variable. your variable is in `$_GET['act']` not in `$_GET['vw']`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting a cached version of worker because you are not sending the data correctly, therefore the address is just `worker.php`. I think the data should be sent as an object like this:

```
data: { pageref: 'streets', act: 'vw' },
```